# How to add specific text to the first of sentence with Regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to add specific text to the first of the sentences
these sentences can be everything,
How can I do this with Regex?
For example, we have a text file and this file has 12 lines
and I would like to add specific text to the first of every line
How can I do this with Regex?
Specific text can be everything with characters and numbers
and texts in lines can be everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, it was ^ character.
Thanks for watching this question
for more information please see this Tutorial
[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions)